# Google Analytics search for containing words not working

Tags: search, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

In google analytics, I'm on the User Explorer and I have my own variable for User ID.

The attached image is a preview before I press search. Searching for rows that contain "BAPC" results in empty results even though I can clearly see they're are BAPC rows.

I also tried "ends with" instead of "containing" and still doesnt work. Is the search broke in analytics or am I missing something?

[image: Searching for rows that contain "BAPC" results in empty results]

Answer (score 0):

The filters don't seem to work in this report (except if you enter the entire string to isolate an user Id or if you filter the metrics).